# Is there an html character entity which can represent "Admin"?

Tags: html, admin

I'm looking for a way to represent a user as an admin, and would prefer to use an html entity to do so. (http://www.amp-what.com/)

Does anyone have any suggestions, or is this a fruitless search?

Comment: By "HTML character entity" you mean "Unicode character". The key suggestion below from Dave is &#128273;

Comment: just noticed (via looking at this post on the stack exchange app on my android phone) that these html entities can render differently. i.e. the shield icon didn't show at all and the key appeared at an angle rather than straight up like in my answer on a desktop (i.e.) - so just concerned about the use of them - are they reliable?

Comment: @DaveHaigh all depends on the capabilities of the font. But with a code like 128273 (1F511 in hex) you are off Unicode plane zero and into the supplemental multilingual plane. It is very likely that there will be problems across devices. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29

Answer (score 3):

By 'html entity' I'm guessing you mean an icon, please correct me or update your question if I am mistaken.

If I am right, then you want to distinguish an admin icon from a normal user icon. Therefore whatever icon you use for a normal user, if you take that and couple it with a **key or badge icon**, it could represent a more advanced version of a user e.g. admin.

**e.g.**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I actually clicked on the link in your question and see what you mean now :)

You could use a shield ⛨ or key 🔑 icon maybe to represent admin.

Comment: shield icon is what i was gonna say

Comment: or Police officer  or Lock and key 

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `#` symbol which is the command prompt that superusers/root get by default in many Unix-like shells (including Linux, MacOSX, and Android).
 Another possible alternative, assuming that your users might have visited one of stackexchange websites is the diamond symbol ♦ that is used here for community moderators.

As far as I can tell, there is no universally recognized admin symbols. These kind symbol I mentioned above is as universal as it can be. Therefore make sure to include the word admin somewhere near the icon, preferably next to the icon itself or at least when you hover over the symbol.

Comment: Since  most computer users in the world never used Unix(-like) shells, still less as root, I think the important part is “there is no universally recognized admin symbols”.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: yes, you're correct, that, and to add the word admin as a hint what it means whatever symbols you end up using.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the purpose is to distinguish admin users from normal users in a list of users or in some presentation where different user names may appear. There is no symbol reserved for this purpose, so you need to choose a method suitable for the rendering context, using something that indicates some user names as “more important” or “more powerful”. The choice should also depend on the purpose of indicating admins in some special way. And you probably need a legend somewhere, telling what the notation means.

In most rendering contexts, you can use a distinctive color or background color or bolding, though these have accessibility concerns when used alone.

A simple character that probably conveys the idea of importance, emphasis, or “something special” is the common asterisk “*”. However, its glyphs vary a lot and are often superscript-like and small. So you might consider using one of the many star-like characters in Unicode, such as “✶” U+2736 SIX POINTED BLACK STAR (`&#x2736;`), perhaps in color. However, you would then have a font problem, since relatively few fonts contain such characters.

Alternatively, unless this is for a plain text context, consider using an image, e.g. with “ADM” in smallish size in a special font and with distinctive background and text colors (and naturally with something like `alt="admin"` when using an `img` element in HTML).

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, html entity for admin kind of icon search is fruitless effort.

However, I would recommend to use font awesome for such interface presentation using Unicode;


Btw, use CSS code that sets font-family: FontAwesome and font-style: normal on the i element.
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Hope this helps in your task.